# getting undefined variable in laravel view 5.7

Tags: laravel

getting undefined variable in my view

```
public function confirm()
    {
        $data = Transaction::select('number','total','package')->where('user_id','=',\Auth::user_id()->id)->first();

       return view('user.package',compact('data'));

    }
```

// My view

```
 <center> 
<h3 class="card-title"><b>You are about to buy {{$data->number}} package of {{$data->package}} for {{$data->total}}</b>
</h3>
</center>
```

Comment: have you checked if your `$data` is null for some reason? Because `first()` returns null if it cannot find the row.

Comment: @nakov $data is not null

Comment: Can you share the full and exact error message? What does `$data` exactly contain?

Comment: can you show your Transaction Model and table

Comment: $data is a variable check the code above @NicoHaase

Comment: And what **exactly** does `$data` contain? Can you add some dump of it to the question?

Answer (score 2):

change to `\Auth::user_id()->id` to `\Auth::user()->id`

```
$data = Transaction::select('number','total','package')->where('user_id',\Auth::user()->id)->first();
```

by getting current authenticate user id two ways.

```
1.Auth::id();
2.Auth::user()->id
```

in your view check like that `isset condition row is exist or not`

```
            @isset($data)
                <center> 
                   <h3 class="card-title"><b>You are about to buy {{$data->number}} package of {{$data->package}} for {{$data->total}}</b>
                  </h3>
                </center>
             @endif
```

Comment: that's not the problem though i corrected that.... still showing undefined variable data

Comment: thanks but that's not what i wan't. i just want to pass that variable to the view so i can output the data

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ->get() instead of ->first()

Comment: i don't want to use a foreach loop that's why i'm using first instead of get

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
use Auth;
public function confirm()
{
    $data = Transaction::select('number','total','package')->where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)->first();

   return view('user.package',compact('data'));

}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to the code such that others can learn from it?

Answer (score 0):

Try `auth()->user()->id` instead of `\Auth::user_id()->id`

or 
You can use an Eloquent relation like

```
$user->with('Transaction')->select('number','total','package')->first();
```

Comment: Can you explain how that solves the issue of having an undefined index notice?